# pg_search and multi column indexing (Rails 4)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, pg-search, multiple-columns

I have a full-text search query in PostgreSQL that looks like this:

```
to_tsvector('english', coalesce("products"."name"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce("products"."uid"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce("products"."serial"::text, ''));
```

But creating a migration like this does not work for some reason:

```
create_trigger(compatibility: 1).on(:products).before(:insert, :update) do
  "new.tsv_body := to_tsvector('english', coalesce("products"."name"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce("products"."uid"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce("products"."serial"::text, ''));"
end
```

Any advice?

Comment: whenever you write "does not work", that's a sign you need to delete those words and replace them with an actual description of why it does not work. What does it do / not do? What effect did you expect? What actually happened? Were there any error messages or log messages?

Comment: Point taken. It was a terribly posted question. The answer below worked, when I commented out the double-quotes the migration ran. Then I tried to run:
    Product.find_each(&:touch)
in the console and got this error:
    PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "products"

Comment: Sounds like "new question" material to me. With details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is in how Stack Overflow has syntax-highlighted your program text:

```
  "new.tsv_body := to_tsvector('english', coalesce("products"."name"::text, '')) .... )
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
```

You've included double-quotes around the table and column names. The whole string is in double quotes. So these inset double quotes *end the string*.

You'll need to escape them, or omit them. I don't do Ruby / Rails, but if it's anything like most languages, backslash escapes are appropriate:

```
"new.tsv_body := to_tsvector('english', coalesce(\"products\".\"name\"::text, '')) .... )
```